# Xamarin - ToolbarItems

Tags: xamarin-forms

Na aplicação eu tenho 2 itens do ToolbarItem `(ToolbarItem Name="Digitar" Activated="Digitar" ToolbarItem Name="Procurar" Icon="procurar48.png" Activated="Procurar")`, o primeiro é uma palavra e o segundo é uma lupa. O que quero fazer é quando clicar na lupa deixar a lupa invisível e habilitar o espaço da palavra para digitar o item procurado. É uma coisa bem simples mas que em Xamarin está dando muito trabalho.

**Meu código .cs**

```
   private void Procurar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolbarItems.Remove(Digitar);
    }
```

Acontece que dessa forma está dando erro na palavra Digitar(Não é possivel converter de "grupo de métodos" para "ToolbarItem"